# Should I ask users to upload images or host them elsewhere and provide the link?

Tags: web-applications

I'm developing an app that includes the basic functionality of allowing a user to display a photo on a public facing page.

Looking for some perspective on whether it's better practice to go for image file uploads or have users supply links to images that are already hosted elsewhere.

What are the considerations for choosing? Doesn't it make more sense to skip the burden of transferring and hosting images and just have them hosted elsewhere (ie Flickr, Photobucket, etc.)?

Comment: What are the images for? Just a profile picture or is it important that the images stay alive? The risk of having the user upload the image offsite is that the image may be removed.

Comment: To guarantee the quality of your app, best practice is to host the images yourself, either on your personal server or a pay a 3rd party to do so. As Brandon mentioned, the images my be removed which will reflect on your app.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to host the images for many reasons if you have the space to do it:

- you have control of what your site is sending
- if your site is on then the image will display and you don't rely on some possibly obscure server to display the images
- you don't require the user to have another site to store his image
- many people have no clue about how to supply a link to their images

Answer (score 0):

There are implications of either approach.  Having users store images on other servers means that you introduce a dependency into your architecture.  If they choose to store them on a server that happens to be down when someone accesses your page, those images won't be available.  But you get the benefit of not having to deal with them.

It can be considered bad practice in some situations to reference images from other servers as you are essentially "stealing bandwidth" for those images that are hosted on other servers.  See http://altlab.com/hotlinking.html for more discussion on this.

By not controlling where the images are hosted, you won't control the browser cache-ability of the images.  If you host them then you can set appropriate caching headers so that images may be browser cached for better performance when the images are used for repeated page views.  Essentially, if they are not on your server, you give up some of the ability to control and use them as you see fit.

Using another source such as Flickr means you get a ton of pre-developed APIs.  Essentially, if you use the other server as a service then you get all the benefits of using a service.  But if it up to users to pick the location, these benefits may not be realized because they may select to host their images on a sub-par source.

These are some of the things to think about.  There may not be a "right" answer--but there will be trade-offs with either approach.

Answer (score 0):

I will just mention the cons as pros are kind of apparent

**Uploaded elsewhere Cons**

- No direct control on the images (some may be deleted as abuse etc)
- Copyright issues
- APIs may be changed, site may be down, URL pattern changed
- Policies might be changed

**Self-hosted Cons**

- Lots of resources required
- Need to setup moderation team (to make sure they are not abusive)
- May be targeted for some XSS attacks and hence extra security concerns

Looking at the above for me, self-hosted is a better option

Answer (score 0):

Its probably worth noting that Stackoverflow uses imgur.com to host images that are attached to posts that aren't links and works reasonably well, but does have the downsides previously mentioned.

Additionally there are two other problems not previously mentioned.

1. While SO may not be blocked by some organizations imgur.com might be. For example I can't see any images on SO posts when I'm at work
2. If you're not careful in the way you code your site [unpredicable things may happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89734/148672)